# Software for in-place editing of the PNG image in Microsoft Word

Tags: image-editor, microsoft-word

What is a good software for in-place editing of the PNG image in Microsoft Word? Need to remove text lines in 50 figures in my CS thesis. Can't do it with Photoshop without cutting it from Word document. Need a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't keep the originals? And you don't know the source any more? Well, ... if that's gonna be a good thesis then? Ok, anyway, is it in DOC or DOCX format?

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming your thesis in Mathematics..

In mathematics, generally we use diagrams,

for that diagrams, you can go with

### 1. Geogebra or

### 2. Inkscape

Both are good to edit..  In Geogebra, you can easily draw if you diagram contains mathematical figures. Suppose your diagram contains more complications, I suggest you to go to inkscape, which is giving an option know as image tracing and colouring it as you like..

both are free version available here..

[geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/download)

[inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/)

Comment: Could you explain how to edit PNGs with Inkscape? And next, how to run Inkscape within Word? This answer is technically not correct.